# Does TensorFlow support to save the initial hyper-parameter configuration automatically?

Tags: tensorflow

We need to run the designed networks many times for better performance and it would be better to record our experiments we have run. Maybe it could be good to provide to record these `hyper-parameter configuration` automatically by the `tensorflow` execution engine. For example, I record by set different directory name for the log directory as:

```
log_lr_0.001_theta_0.1_alpha_0.1
log_lr_0.01_theta_0.01_alpha_0.02
....
```

Are there any automatic ways to help this? In addition, it would be better that when we start a new `tensorflow` training instance, a new port will be allocated and a new `tensorboard` is started and shows its learning state.

Comment: Tensorflow doesn't know about any of your hyper-params

Comment: Yes. Thanks for comment. Because sometime I forgot what the hyper-params are for some log directories when I modified the code. Maybe the tensorflow can introduce a log module or system to do this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, tensorflow doesn't support initial hyper parameter configuration automatically.

I've faced the same issue as you, and I'm using a tool called [Sacred](https://github.com/IDSIA/sacred), I hope you'd find that useful.